# What is the probability that an enlarged hand contains at least $3$ kings

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, card-games

Question: A card hand selected from a standard deck consists of $2$ kings, $1$ queen, $1$ jack, and $1$ ten. Three additional cards are selected at random and without replacement from the remaining cards in the deck. What is the probability that the enlarged hand contains at least $3$ kings?
 There are $47$ cards remaining in the deck. Two are kings and $45$ are non-kings. My thinking is: if two kings are left in the deck, how am I supposed to get $3$? This looks like a binomial coefficient problem in my opinion. Need help.

Comment: You already have two kings: all you need is **one** more.

Comment: right but its without replacement and its $47$ cards left with $2$ kings gone

Comment: Exactly, so you need to pick either 1 or 2 kings from the 47 cards remaining in the pack.

Comment: if $2$ are gone from the deck, would that leave $2$ more only? I don't see where I am getting a third king from

Comment: You get three kings via the two in your hand plus the one or two that you draw from the deck. It's three total kings, not three kings in the newly drawn cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obtain three or more kings so long as you don't draw zero kings, so the answer is

$$1-P(\text{zero kings})=1-\frac{45}{47}\cdot\frac{44}{46}\cdot\frac{43}{45}=\frac{135}{1081}\approx 0.125$$

Comment: I see but when the question said $2$ are gone without replacement, I was under the impression that I have only $2$ kings left

Comment: @behold I don't understand how that is an objection to what I had written. Can you point to exactly which part of my expression you don't understand/think is wrong?

Comment: Not yours, It was my way of approaching the problem. Yours seem legit